# AngularJS textbox value returns undefined

Tags: function, angularjs, mode

When I press my button, I want to print the value of my textbox in my console. But my textbox returns a undefined. It seems that all of the code are working perfect, I did it the same way as some other code I used before, but it isn't working now.

This is my html code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">    
     <input type="text" ng-model="add" ng-model-instant><button class="btn" ng-click="order()"><i class="icon-plus"></i>Order!</button>
</form>
```

This is my script:

```
angular.module('MyApp', []).
config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.  
        when('/boeken', {templateUrl:'partials/boeken.html', controller:BoekenCtrl}).
        when('/orders', {templateUrl:'partials/orders.html', controller:OrderCtrl}).
        when('/home', {templateUrl:'partials/home.html', controller:HomeCtrl}).
        otherwise({redirectTo:'/home'});
});

//BoekenCtrl

//HomeCtrl

function OrderCtrl($rootScope) {    
    $rootScope.order = function() { console.log($rootScope.add); $rootScope.add = "";     };
}
```

Why is it that my textbox is undefined?

Comment: please, show all your code. Sounds you have problem with controller. And why do you use `$rootScope`?

Comment: Added more of my code. The BoekenCtrl and HomeCtrl are working fine. I use the $rootScope 'cause the app is simple and a service is not needed.

Comment: SO your form refers to `OrderCtrl`. did you try to print log into `OrderCtrl` (not in function)? I think instead `$rootScope.order = function()` use `$scope.order = function()`. Because in html you use specific `scope`. WHat about `body?` ng-controller="OrderCtrl"?

Comment: Yes, my form uses the OrderCtrl and try'd to print it into OrderCtrl. It say's undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead

```
function OrderCtrl($rootScope) {    
$rootScope.order = function() { console.log($rootScope.add); $rootScope.add = "";     };
}
```

use:

```
function OrderCtrl($scope) {    
$scope.order = function() {
    console.log($scope.add);
    $scope.add = "";
 };
}
```

Since your form exists under `OrderCtrl`, you need to use `$scope` into `OrderCtrl` controller to fetch any data. But, sure, you can store it after in `$rootScope`

Please, see the example in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xVKcr/23/)

Comment: Did you mean $rootscope.order or $scope.orde. 'Cause $scope.order gives an error.

Comment: because `OrderCtrl` stay with `$rootScope` only, sorry, fixed

Comment: The problem isn't solved with the code above. Still get the undefined.

Comment: I posted Fiddle, please take a look.